# Correct result of amount of repeated values of array

Tags: javascript

I have written this code for detecting repetitive values of an array. But, it shows incorrect results, how to fix it?

```
  function RepeatedValues(str) {
 let repeatedCount = 0;
 const array = str.split("").slice().sort();

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { 
         if(array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
             ++repeatedCount;
             console.log(array[i] + ", " + repeatedCount);
         }
         else {
             repeatedCount = 0;
         }
     }
 
}
```

Output:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3KRB.png)

Comment: You're resetting `repeatedCount` every time you advance to an index where the next character is not the same

Comment: Always try to dry run your code on paper by taking a suitable test case. This will help you in finding the bug.

Comment: I took away this:  else {repeatedCount = 0;} but it still continues to show the incorrect result

Comment: What is the expected count? Do you want one number per repeated character or one total number of repeating characters? Also. please don't post images with only text, it's better to include the text directly.

Comment: one total number of each repeated character

Comment: @YaroslavYatsyk I just updaed my answer below to also log repeated charachters at the end of the sorted array. Is you issue resolved now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you do not log the result at the right place. Only once the next character has stopped being the same have you found all duplicates (aka. in your `else` block).

Next, your count starts at 0, so if you want to see `r, 2` and you have counted 1 repetition, do `repeatedCount + 1`.

```js
function RepeatedValues(str) {
  console.log(str)
  let repeatedCount = 0;
  const array = str.split("").slice().sort();

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
      ++repeatedCount;
      continue;
    }

    if (repeatedCount > 0) {
      console.log(array[i] + ", " + (repeatedCount + 1));
    }

    repeatedCount = 0;
  }

  if (repeatedCount > 0) {
    console.log(array[i] + ", " + (repeatedCount + 1));
  }
}

RepeatedValues("bri2ghtwork2")
RepeatedValues("showreel")
RepeatedValues("circumstances")
RepeatedValues("Mississippi")
```

Note: I have taken the liberty of replacing your else block with a `continue` in the `if` block. In my opinion this makes the function easier to understand and 'flatter'.

Comment: @YaroslavYatsyk You're very welcome. Does that help you fix your issue? If so, I'd appreciate an upvote and the answer marked as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left.